# Inserting GeoDataFrame into existing schema

Tags: python, postgis, psycopg2, sqlalchemy

Is there a straightforward way to insert a GeoDataFrame into an existing schema? I love the `geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_postgis` but this creates a new schema. I only need to insert a table into an existing schema.

Answer (score 2):

geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_postgis should not be creating a new schema. It will throw an error if the specified schema does not exist.

If you have created the schema, this should work just fine:

```
gdf.to_postgis('tablename', con, schema='schemaname')
```

Comment: Goodness. That makes sense. I had it right in front of my eyes. Thank you!